# How to detect ENTER keypress/ or the "GO" button in the Address Bar?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect the ENTER keypress of the Address Bar and also, the "Go(to the specified URL)" button using Javascript.
As per my previous efforts using "keycode==13" did not work as required.
say, in the following code:

> ```
> window.onkeypress = testKeyEvent;
>
> function testKeyEvent(e) {
>     if (e.keyCode == 13) //We are using Enter key press event for test purpose.
>     {
>         alert('Enter key pressed');
>     }
>     else //If any other button pressed.
>     {
>         alert('Not Enter key pressed');
>     }
> }    </script>
> ```

I want first the Alert box to be displayed,after I have typed any URL(valid or not) in the address box and Pressed ENTER/ Clicked GO button and then go to specified URL.

Is it Possible? I know I am missing out on a lot of things, Please mention about them.

Comment: what address bar? the one built into the browser? or is it an input on your page?

Comment: You can't, you can only get events for elements on the page itself, you have no visibility on the browser address bar.

Comment: You could use the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event to detect when the user is about to navigate away from the webpage, that might work for what you want. Note that apparently browsers can ignore code trying to use `alert` during the handler for that event though, so that could cause you problems.

Comment: @epascarello The built-in one

Comment: unless you are building a plug in, not going to happen

Answer (score 3):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, I don't think you can do this, because the context in which the JavaScript runs stops at the Document (meaning, JavaScript doesn't even quite know that the browser itself exists).

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect the keystroke because it's outside your window, but you can detect navigation away from your page like

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    alert("Leaving page...");
}
```

Comment: Note the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) though - browsers are free to ignore `alert` in this context, and when I tested that(Chrome 58 on Linux), that is what happens,so this code actually  does nothing. What you can do is `return` some value from the function instead- that gives you the `Are you sure you want to leave?` dialogue.

Comment: You're right.  Reliably detecting leaving a page across platforms is a problem.

Comment: Also because it's an area that's been abused by advertisers in the past, browsers and standards lock things down.

Comment: @KarlReid It doesn't work even when I am trying to return an alert box.