# JavaScript event listener for browser address bar

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to redirect the search when the user searches from the browser address bar. Is there any event listener that would notice when the user hits 'enter' on the browser address bar?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect ENTER keypress/ or the "GO" button in the Address Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440813/how-to-detect-enter-keypress-or-the-go-button-in-the-address-bar)

Comment: No. This isn't targeting the address bar. So it can't be done then, i guess.